# result not working in cfquery using railo

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, railo

I'm trying to get the value of the ID just inserted. NOTE: the column I'm trying to get is datatype uniqueidentifier created with default value newid()

The below code is what I'm trying to run:

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" result="newReplyID">
    INSERT INTO nlforums_Reply(AnswerID, ReplyValue, UserID, CreateDateTime)
    VALUES( <cfqueryparam value="#form.originalMessageID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.replyValue#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.userID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.posted#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE">
           )
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#newReplyID['IDENTITYCOL']#" />
```

The error I get: key [IDENTITYCOL] doesn't exist

Here's what happens if I dump #newReplyID#

[image]

Comment: What are you getting when you do `<cfdump var="#newReplyID#">` ?

Comment: editted the question

Comment: I have not much experience in Railo, But as per the link http://www.intermedia.com.au/railo-context/doc/tags.cfm?item=cfquery I think it does not contains the IDENTITYCOL attribute in `result`.

Comment: Hope this helps. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2178

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what works. The result attribute doesn't work on a UUID.

```
<cfquery datasource="#ds#" name="newReplyID">
    INSERT INTO nlforums_Reply(AnswerID, ReplyValue, UserID, CreateDateTime)
    OUTPUT inserted.ReplyID 
    VALUES( <cfqueryparam value="#form.originalMessageID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.replyValue#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_LONGVARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.userID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
            <cfqueryparam value="#form.posted#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE">
           )
</cfquery>
<cfdump var="#newReplyID#" />
```

Comment: If the field is a UUID, why don't you just create one with ColdFusion and use it?

Comment: @DanBracuk - Because it sounds like it is the table's PK which is automatically populated by SQL Server, just like with an IDENTITY column, only it uses a UUID.

Comment: Good on you for coming back with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you dig a little deeper you might find that IDENTITYCOL has been deprecated and is no longer available from SQL Server 2012 forward.

This solution still works nicely though:

    INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, etc)
    OUTPUT inserted.IDcolumnName 
    VALUES(1,2,etc)

Comment: (Edit - typo fix) You may be thinking of a different feature. In CF, `result.IDENTITYCOL` refers to the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value retrieved by the application server after an INSERT query is executed. It is very different than the deprecated SQL Server feature mentioned here:  ["IDENTITYCOL as a column name in DML statements...."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). Though agreed, the OUTPUT technique [already mentioned in the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26621630/104223) works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [queryExecute](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/coldfusion-11-queryexecute.html) instead?

Comment: Definitely nicer syntax. I do not think it will make a difference though. The reason for the error is that their PK is type UUID, not identity. So the INSERT does not return an identity value. Hence the "IDENTITYCOL doesn't exist" error.